# Laravel multiple authentication

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

So i have a complete web app where users can CRUD portfolios after they signup/login.
I have another app and want to put both of them under a single domain, so users can access them like this:
**portfolios.mysite.com 
 forums.mysite.com** 
I made the forum app with the Auth that comes with laravel. (*php artisan make:auth*). How can i add the forums app to it, so that users can access either the **portfolios** or **forums** area and Create/update/delete/read portfolios or write posts in the forum.

Comment: Just to be clear, you want users that are logged into `portfolios.mysite.com` to also be logged into `forums.mysite.com`, right?

Comment: When you mean separated, though, do you want the same credentials to work on both sites, or entirely separated (as in different registration, login in, etc.)?

Comment: In that case, it would just be easier to have two different Laravel sites. Two entirely separate Laravel sites, each one with its own database.

Comment: I know it is hell lot easier to have them each on its own domain, (actually that's my backup plan).
Do you think it is good if i add an extra column in the db and store the user type (whether portfolios or forum) on it, then check it after each login attempt?

Comment: No, I do not. The correct way to go with it is two different Laravel installations as the two sites are in no way interconnected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After clarification, I understand that you want the two sites to be entirely independent.

In that case, it would just be easier (and clearer) to have two different Laravel sites. Two entirely separate Laravel sites, each one with its own database.

Comment: Sorry :(

However, I believe that one day you will thank me.

Comment: Not trying to advertise, but I'd honestly recommend DigitalOcean (or Linode, or any type of VPS service). Just set up your own droplet and you could host as many sites as you want. This is what I use both for business and pleasure

Comment: Yes you can. You will need to do your research of course. You're gonna need to point your subdomains to your droplet's IP and then move all of your sites to your server.